# How can I run a python script through brownie from a typescript?

Tags: python, typescript, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I am developing a solidity smart contract and I'm deploying it through a python code that I run through brownie with command lines.
Also, I am developing a front-end dApp with typescript to interact and also to deploy those contracts. Using useDApp allows me to interact with already deployed contracts, but I still haven't figured out how to deploy those contracts through the front-end.

To make it short, the "deploy.py" code has a function that deploys the solidity code and it passes to the contract some variables to the constructor. It works fine.

On the front-end of the App (typescript) I have a form that users can fill out, and then when they click on the "send" button, those fields turn into variables.
All I need now is to pass those variables to the "deploy.py" file so it can cast them to the solidity constructor, and, of course, deploy the contract through brownie.

---

Update:

Found out that the easier way to do this is to forget the python part and deploy the contract directly with ethers.js ContractFactory. Couldn't solve it until now though, but on my way to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make the front end talk with python backend is to create a restful api with Flask. So when you submit the form, you will send a post request to python server, python flask will extract the posted data with `request.json`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
# allow only post request here
@app.route('/deploy_contract_route', methods = ['POST'])
def deploy_contract():
   content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
   if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.json
        # json includes the post data. now you past this to deploy request. you get individual fields data
        deploy_contract_script(pass_args_here):
            # what ever deploying logic runs here
            
            return value_to_front_end
   else:
      return 'Content-Type not supported!'
```